# HTML submit button in Edge has broken outset border, but correct inset border

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

Edge creates the perfect inset border, but the outset border is wrong.

Pictures here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1osq.jpg

The only change in code between these two pictures is changing the border-style from outset to inset.  Why are the colors not exactly the same but swapped?

```
.SmallButton {
    color: grey;
    font-family: "Segoe UI";
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border-style: inset;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    margin-top: 20px !important;
    width: 230px !important;
    height: 36px !important;    
}
```

```
<input class="SmallButton" type="submit" value="Sign Up">
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers sometimes have slightly different approaches on how to display certain UI elements. It's best to style them manually by applying specific CSS properties.

You can change the `border-style` to solid and apply `border-color` for each side to get the preferred result.

```css
.button {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 18px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px;
    color: #808080;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 36px;
    max-width: 230px;
    width: 100%;
}

.button-outset {
    border-color: #F0F0F0 #A0A0A0 #A0A0A0 #F0F0F0;   
}

.button-inset {
    border-color: #A0A0A0 #F0F0F0 #F0F0F0 #A0A0A0;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" class="button button-outset" value="Outset button">

<br><br>

<input type="submit" class="button button-inset" value="Inset button">
```

Comment: The code snippet I made works in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Edge and IE 11. I double checked it to be sure. I noticed you are applying the !important flag multiple times, so maybe some other CSS is influencing your button styling. Try to avoid using !important as much as possible.

Comment: Weirdly enough, it worked when I did border-color: #DDDDDD #A0A0A0 #A0A0A0 #DDDDDD;   instead?  I tried your border-color again and it didn't work.  So I used the dropped tool and found it to be #DDDDDD which worked.

Comment: You can change to colors to your liking. It's in top, right, bottom, left order. Nice it worked out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kees! Very helpful.